# Id3 Tags not properly recognised

Tags: applications, id3-tag

I have so far tried a number of applications to listen to music on my Android phone, and I'm for now settled with Google's Play Music. However, it has the same issue of every other app I've tried. Let me try to explain with a real issue: I've got Anouk's Together Alone album. All the songs have the same album tags. However, Play Music likes to show 2+7 songs (9 songs in album) as 2 different albums, as seen in the below screenshot. How do I fix that?

[image]

Comment: If all apps have the same 'issue' then I'd guess that it's actually the ID3 tags that are the problem. They might look the same but any difference will be detected as a different album. Try editing the tags and make sure they are **exactly** the same.

Comment: I've  tried doing that a number of times to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only fix I know is to delete the tags from both albums and then re-tag the songs from the two albums. Unfortunately that will need to happen manually.